# Website crashes in IE9 Only

Tags: internet-explorer, responsive-design, internet-explorer-9

My [web page](http://webdesign199.com/landing.php) freezes/crashes immediately in IE9 only, which is before I can see any errors in the console.

Also, I did get the site to work by adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

But, having modern IE browsers render as IE8 mode is less than ideal.

I even tried isolating the use of the meta tag with an IE9 conditional comment, but that doesn't work.

So, if anyone knows the issue, or even a band-aid to get only IE9 into IE8 mode would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I don't see any errors:
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwebdesign199.com%2Flanding.php

Comment: It works fine for me on IE9 using Microsoft's VM. Could it be something with the computer itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to narrow it down to the following files (i.e., the JS files for <= IE8 versions found on almost every responsive site):

- html5shiv.js
- respond.min.js

I switched to a CDN version of these files and it resolved the issue.  So, I assume I had an older version w/ a bug that was fixed in a later release.

Still not sure why IE9 would be affected.  Also, I did test this on CrossBrowserTesting.com, so it wasn't just my PC.

Thanks to everyone who replied.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted some code, but try validating you web page here:

http://validator.w3.org/

I bet you have a bad HTML tag.

Comment: There's a link to the page in my question.

Comment: Also, I don't see any errors:https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwebdesign199.com%2Flanding.php

Answer (score 0):

Using this meta tag will put IE9, but not 10 or 11, in IE8 mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11,10,8">
```